# At what point does the Singleton instantiation and "static" Code Occur

Tags: java, singleton

I have two questions about the Singleton class below:

1) At what point in the code does the instance get invoked, via the "new" in the declaration? Is it the *first time the getInstance()* gets called?

2) At what point in the code does the "static {..}" HashMap initialization occur?

```
public class Factory {

    // Singleton Member Defined - when does this New instantiation occur
    private static final Factory instance = new Factory();

    // Additional Map Variable
    private static HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        myMap.put("key1", "value1");
        myMap.put("key2", "value2");
    }

    // Private Constructor for Singleton
    private Factory() {
    }

    // Get Singleton Instance
    public Factory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables and static blocks are called once when the class is first loaded by the JVM (first call of your class in the code).

The order of declaration defines the order of loading.

Comment: What about the new Factory() one-time instantiation?

Comment: (Never mind, they're a static variable and static block) That answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both of those are executed the moment the class gets loaded (so typically when the class is referenced somewhere for the first time).

All static members will get initiated and all static blocks will be executed. This happens from the top of the class to the bottom.

So it is not when getInstance() is called. It happens earlier than that.

Answer (score 0):

Same as what [`Medhi Redjem`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075373/medhi-redjem) said...

But your code will needs to create an instance to get an instance like:

```
Factory factory = new Factory().getInstance();
```

Usually getInstance methodes doesn't works like that

Try this code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Factory {

    private static final HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        myMap.put("key2", "value2");
        myMap.put("key1", "value1");
    }

    private Factory() {

    }

    public static Factory getInstance() {
        return new Factory();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory factory = Factory.getInstance();
    }
}
```